# Как разместить динамически создаваемые виджеты на QMainWindow?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qlayout, qscrollarea

Как можно программно создавать разные виджеты и добавлять их в макет?

То есть таких различных виджетов может быть много и они скроллятся на форме в рамках окна. Но нужно управлять границами каждого виджета. Или, например, скрывать по нажатию кнопки из виджета.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()

        """  
        Здесь необходимо генерировать различные виджеты (с абсолютным позиционированием элементов внутри) и добавлять их в макет
        """
        #self.vbox.addWidget()

        self.widget.setLayout(self.vbox)

        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.scroll)

        self.setGeometry(600, 100, 1000, 900)
        self.setWindowTitle('MainWindow')
        self.show()

        return

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Об абсолютным позиционированием вам лучше знать только то, что оно есть и все.

Более практично управлять виджетами через Layout-ы

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)

        """  
        Здесь необходимо генерировать различные виджеты 
        (с абсолютным позиционированием элементов внутри) и добавлять их в макет
        """
        #self.vbox.addWidget()

        for i in range(20):
            w = QWidget()
            hbox = QHBoxLayout(w)
            label = QLabel(f'Label {i}')
            lineEdit = QLineEdit(f'LineEdit {i}')
            button = QPushButton(f'Button {i}')
            button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, lb=label, le=lineEdit: self.onClick(lb, le))
            hbox.addWidget(label)
            hbox.addWidget(lineEdit)
            hbox.addWidget(button)

            self.vbox.addWidget(w)

        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.scroll)

    def onClick(self, lb, le):
        #print(lb.text(), le.text())
        lb.setText(le.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.setWindowTitle('Title MainWindow')
    main.resize(700, 400)
    main.show()                    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]