# Динамическое создание кнопок

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, функции, qpushbutton

Недавно начал писать код на *PyQt5*, и решил написать программу, где будет много кнопок. Чтобы было удобно, решил сделать кнопку в функции и в нужном моменте вызывать её указав настройки.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QMessageBox, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFontDatabase, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFontDatabase, QFont

  
class Button(QPushButton):
    mouseMoved = pyqtSignal()
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.mouseMoved.emit()

class Example(QWidget): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        #def кнопки, теперь надо просто прописать название def'а и прописать ему данные!
        def skins(btn_name, text, resize, resize_2, move, move_2, mains, color):
            self.btn_name = QPushButton(self)
            self.btn_name.setMouseTracking(True);
            self.btn_name.setText(text)
            self.btn_name.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(image/img2.png); color: " + color + "; border-radius: 4px;}QPushButton:pressed {background-image: url(image/img2.1.png) }")
            self.btn_name.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
            self.btn_name.resize(resize, resize_2)
            self.btn_name.move(move, move_2)
            self.btn_name.clicked.connect(mains)
        skins(self.btn1, "текст", 300, 150, 0, 1550, self.ObjectKill, "White")
    def ObjectKill(self):
        self.btn1.close()
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Но мне выдаёт ошибку:

> AttributeError: Example' object has no attribute 'btn1'

Что делать?

`Example` - это класс.

---

Длинный вариант (так я делал раньше):

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QMessageBox, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFontDatabase, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFontDatabase, QFont

  
class Button(QPushButton):
    mouseMoved = pyqtSignal()
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.mouseMoved.emit()

class Example(QWidget): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.btn_name = QPushButton(self)
        self.btn_name.setMouseTracking(True);
        self.btn_name.setText(text)
        self.btn_name.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(image/img2.png); color: White; border-radius: 4px;}QPushButton:pressed {background-image: url(image/img2.1.png) }")
        self.btn_name.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn_name.resize(300, 150)
        self.btn_name.move(0, 1550)
        self.btn_name.clicked.connect(self.main)
    def main(self):
        print() 
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

И вот как я хочу реализовать это:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QMessageBox, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFontDatabase, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFontDatabase, QFont

  
class Button(QPushButton):
    mouseMoved = pyqtSignal()
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.mouseMoved.emit()

class Example(QWidget): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        skins(self.btn1, "Текст", 300, 150, 0, 1550, self.ObjectKill, "White")
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Как это возможно сделать?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: 1. Код должен быть текстом, а не картинкой. 2. В проведённом кода нет слова Example. 3. Из сообщения об ошибке понятно, в чем она заключается. Учись читать ошибки.4. Заголовок должен описывать проблему, а не после заполнять место. Здесь каждый вопрос о том, что код не работает.

Comment: Example это класс, в котором происходят все действия, ошибку знаю, как устранить не знаю, поэтому и задал вопрос

Comment: А что делать, если говорят достать из коробки красную книгу, а там красной книги нет?

Comment: class Example(QWidget): 
 def __init__(self):
  super().__init__()
  def skins(btn_name, text, resize, resize_2, move, move_2, mains, color):
   self.btn_name = QPushButton(self)
   self.btn_name.setMouseTracking(True);
   self.btn_name.setText(text)
   self.btn_name.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(image/img2.png); color: " + color + "; border-radius: 4px;}QPushButton:pressed {background-image: url(image/img2.1.png) }")
   self.btn_name.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
   self.btn_name.resize(resize, resize_2)
   self.btn_name.move(move, move_2)

Comment: TFader пожалуйста, прочитайте внимательно что вам пишут в комментариях и то что я вам писал в ответе на ваш предыдущий вопрос, по которому вам надо принять решение - правильный ответ или что не так. Учитывая выше изложенное, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Пример (Длинного варианта) должен быть минимально-воспроизводимым, а не отрывком из чего-то.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не уверен, что правильно вас понял.

Абсолютное позиционирование для размещения виджетов - это плохая практика. 
Вам надо изучить [**Layout Management**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)

В общем динамическое создание виджетов выглядит примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *

  
class Button(QPushButton):
   def __init__(self, num, text, size, color):                 # !!!
        super().__init__()  

        self.setText(f'{text} {num}')                          # !!! {text} {num}
        self.setFixedSize(*size)                               # !!! (*size) 
        
        self.setStyleSheet(f"""
            QPushButton {{                                    /* <---- {{         */
            border-image: url(Ok.png);                        /* <---- border-... */
            color: {color};                                   /* <---- {color}    */ 
            border-radius: 4px;
            }}                                                /* <---- }}         */
            QPushButton:pressed {{
                border-image: url(im.png) 
            }}
        """)   
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))  


class Example(QWidget): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        many_buttons = 16                    # хотим создать 16 кнопок
        column = 4                           # хотим разместить эти кнопки в 4 колонки
        size = (150, 150)                    # размер кнопки, например 150х150 
        color = '#84142D'                    # пускай цвет текста будет такой
        
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        
        for step in range(many_buttons):
            btn = Button(step+1, 'Кнопка', size, color)               # !!!
            btn.clicked.connect(lambda ch, b=btn : self.onClicked(b))
            layout.addWidget(btn, step // column, step % column)        
        
    def onClicked(self, btn):
        # тут выполняются какие-то действия по нажатию на кнопку
        # допустим мы хотим скрыть кнопку, на которуй нажали
        btn.hide() 
        

if __name__ == '__main__':        
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Я попробую еще раз объяснить вам, что для того чтобы вам помочь,
вы должны предоставить **`минимально-воспроизводимый пример`**,
который демонстрирует проблему.

Воспроизводимый означает, что ваш код,
который **`размещен в теле вопроса как обычный текст`**,
копируется и запускается, и мы получаем ошибку, о который вы пишите.

Я не буду обсуждать вашу идею о таком способе размещения кнопок. 
Но если вам так надо, то ваше задача может выглядеть примерно так.

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Label(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, pixmap, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.pixmap = pixmap
        self.start = None

        self.setPixmap(self.pixmap.scaled(self.pixmap.size(),
                Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation))
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setMinimumSize(100, 100)   
        
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton: 
            self.start = event.pos() 
            self._start = event.globalPos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton and self.start: 
            self.end = event.pos()
            self.window().selection.setGeometry(
                QRect(self.start, self.end).normalized())
            self.window().selection.show()
        

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.colors = ['#CF0000', '#FC5404', '#1CC5DC', '#F8F7DE', '#42240C',]
        self.selection = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self) 
        self.selection.setGeometry(QRect())
        self.start = QPointF() 
        self.end = QPointF()

        self.pixmap = QPixmap("boy.jpg")        
        self.label  = Label(self.pixmap, self)  
        self.setFixedSize(self.pixmap.size())
        
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Введите название для кнопки')
        self.lineEdit.setMaxLength(10)
        
        self.pushButton = QPushButton('Создать кнопку')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.create_button)
        
        layout = QGridLayout(self)    
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 2) 
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 1, 1, 1)        
        layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        layout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
                
    def create_button(self):
        if self.selection.geometry() == QRect():
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'Внимание', 
                'Выберите прямоугольник для размещения кнопки.'
            )
            return
            
        x, y = self.selection.geometry().x(), self.selection.geometry().y(),
        size = self.selection.geometry().size()

        self.selection.hide()
        self.selection.setGeometry(QRect())
        
        text = self.lineEdit.text() if self.lineEdit.text() else '???'
        
        btn_name = QPushButton(self.label)
        btn_name.setText(text)
        btn_name.clicked.connect(
            lambda ch, text=btn_name.text(): print(f'Вы кликнули: {text}')
        )
        
        color = random.choice(self.colors)
        btn_name.setStyleSheet(f"""
            QPushButton {{
                border-image: url(Ok.png);   /* <---- установите свое изображение */ 
                color: {color};              /* <---- color                       */ 
                border-radius: 4px;
            }}
            QPushButton:pressed {{
                border-image: url(lena.jpg); /* <---- установите свое изображение */ 
            }}
        """) 
        
        btn_name.setFont(QtGui.QFont(
            "Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold)) 
        btn_name.resize(size) 
        btn_name.move(x, y)
        btn_name.show()
        self.lineEdit.clear()
    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

P.S. Изображение **boy.jpg** вы можете взять [**ЗДЕСЬ**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1352978/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0/1354869#1354869)

Фоновый изображения для кнопок установите любые свои.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: этот ответ не очень подходит под то что я хотел, я имел в виду не создание чего то в запущеном коде, я имел в виду что бы в самом коде можно было создать кнопку/картинку в пару строк, где я укажу настройки её, поэтому я и хотел добавить кнопку в def и в нужном моменте вызывать её, так как у меня в программе будет много кнопок и картинок, а писать большой код не хотелось бы

Comment: @TFader ваши пояснения не не понятны. Попробуйте рассказать лучше что вы хотите сделать и как-то показать изображение окна, которое вы хотите получить. Ошибка, которую вы получаете, говорит о том что объект `btn1` не создан в приложении и поэтому не может быть использован. У вас показан класс `Button` - для чего он вам нужен? Если вы хотите создавать кнопки динамически, объект `btn_name` не должен быть экземпляром класса. Я также не вижу  как вы собираетесь задавать настройки для создаваемой кнопки. ...

Comment: Настройки создаются в месте вызова функции (в скобках), я хочу вместо того что бы писать по 10 строчек на каждую кнопку писать по 1 - 2, пользуясь функцией def, но так как кнопки будут в разных местах, с разным текстом и разными настройками то все это необходимо передать, как это возможно реализовать?

Comment: @TFader я не понимаю что вы хотите сделать. Я много раз отвечал на вопросы о динамическом размещении виджетов, например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1295971 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1334781 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1128920 и т.д. Покажите ваше приложение, в котором вы создаете две кнопки и на описание вашей задумки пишите по 10 строчек и я попробую оптимизировать ваш код.

Comment: @TFader нет, так не пойдет. Все добавления надо писать в теле вопроса, а не в комментариях и с пометкой Uрdate

Comment: Я написал все что говорил в ответе (в комментариях не получается сделать этого)

Comment: Если у вас есть свободное время напишите пожалуйста мне в вк vk.com/v.solovyov3, там я покажу как хотел сделать и объясню